# RDP over SSH with Multiple Hops

Tags: remote-desktop, putty, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect via RDP from a Win-10 workstation through a chain of Linux machines to a remote Windows server. It looks a little like this:

- Windows-A can putty to Nix-1
- Nix-1 can ssh to Nix-2
- Nix-2 can ssh to Nix-3
- Nix-3 is on the same network as Windows-B (to which I need to RDP).

Can anyone suggest the simplest way to achieve this please?

Comment: Is there any way to cut out the middle man and talk straight through windows? A vpn connection if they are on separate networks would be your simplest way

Comment: No - that would have been my first plan.